# Counters in for loops

Tags: java, android, if-statement, for-loop

An expression is displayed on screen, and every time an incorrect answer is submitted it displays hints.

This is my code for a onClick method:

```
TextView setHints = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hints);
    // Get the Answer from your EditText
    String answer =  display.getText().toString();
    setAnswer.setText(answer);

for(int i = 0; i < multiArray.length ; i++)
    {      
        // if the answer is in position 1 of Array [i] 
        if(answer.equals(multiArray[i][1]))
        {
            // We have found the answer, Congratulate the User 
            displayAnswer.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            displayAnswer.setText("CORRECT");
            break;

         }else{
             // Tell them how bad they are since they can't solve simple equations!
             displayAnswer.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
             displayAnswer.setText("INCORRECT");

             for (int count = 0; count<5; count++){
                 if(Prefs.getHints(this)){
                     if (Integer.parseInt(answer) < Integer.parseInt(multiArray[random][1])){
                         setHints.setText("Greater");
                         break;                          
                     }
                     else{
                         setHints.setText("Less");
                     }
                     if (Integer.parseInt(answer) == Integer.parseInt(multiArray[random][1])){
                         setHints.setText("Hints");
                         break;
                     }
                 }

                 if (count > 5){
                     displayAnswer.setText("No Hints Left!");
                     break;
                 }

             }
         }


    }
```

The part that doesn't seem to be working correctly is:

```
if (count > 5){
                     displayAnswer.setText("No Hints Left!");
                     break;
                 }
```

I want `displayAnswer.setText("No Hints Left!");` to be displayed after 4 attempts of clicking the submit button. When i run my app, i still can submit an answer after 5 attempts. What am  i missing here ?

Comment: your `if` statement that seems buggy is inside your `for` loop, you may want to get it outside.

Comment: In your case, are you saying that you should not be able to submit an answer after 5 attempts? Also, you might want to consider what happens when count = 5

Comment: Is your loop set up properly? Once you get into the first `if` you *will* get either a greater/lesser hint, but it looks like you have to pass that in order for the correct, or whatever ("Hints") is doing, `if` to be reached.

Comment: The `"No Hints Left!"` is displayed when there are more than 4 digits entered. If i submit only one digit then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`count` will never be greater than `5`.  It is declared at the top of your `for` loop, which terminates at 4 (`< 5`).  You need to keep an activity-level (class level) variable that will track how many times the button has been clicked, instead of using the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop stops if count = 5

> for (int count = 0; count<5...

but your "No Hints Left!" is only displayed if count > 5.

How about changing both :

> for (int count = 0; count<4...
>
> if (count >=4)

Comment: I have tried this, but now my `displayAnswer` is displaying CORRECT and `No Hints Left` is not being displayed.